# Rails drag-and-drop Sortable Bootstrap Tables - don't save item position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider the drag-and-drop sorting table implemented on [http://benw.me](http://benw.me/posts/sortable-bootstrap-tables/). Table rows are moved - but when I restart the page, the location of the rows is not persisted, and reverts to the original.

**Error query AJAX:**
[screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2qjD.png)

```
update_row_order error 400
```

**Controller:**

```
def update_row_order
    @task = Task.find(task_params[:task_id])
    @task.row_order_position = task_params[:row_order_position]
    @task.save

    render nothing: true # this is a POST action, updates sent via AJAX, no view rendered
  end

private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_thing
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Tasks.coffee:**

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place();

jQuery ->
  if $('#sortable').length > 0
    table_width = $('#sortable').width()
    cells = $('.table').find('tr')[0].cells.length
    desired_width = table_width / cells + 'px'
    $('.table td').css('width', desired_width)

    $('#sortable').sortable(
      axis: 'y'
      items: '.item'
      cursor: 'move'

      sort: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.addClass('active-item-shadow')
      stop: (e, ui) ->
        ui.item.removeClass('active-item-shadow')
        # highlight the row on drop to indicate an update
        ui.item.children('td').effect('highlight', {}, 1000)
      update: (e, ui) ->
        item_id = ui.item.data('item-id')
        console.log(item_id)
        position = ui.item.index() # this will not work with paginated items, as the index is zero on every page
        $.ajax(
          type: 'POST'
          url: '/tasks/update_row_order'
          dataType: 'json'
          data: { thing: {task_id: item_id, row_order_position: position } }
        )
    )
```

Comment: Do you have the code available that is sending the AJAX call?

Comment: Added to question my `controller` and `tasks.coffe` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem, make sure to include :task_id in the tasks_params. So it should look like:

```
def task_params
params.require(:task).permit(:task_id, :other_params, :row_order_position, :other_param)
end
```